# Push notification in create react app using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification

Can someone please help me integrate push notification using firebase into my create-react-app web application? I have tried to follow some articles, but nothing worked - can someone please help me with a working tutorial or a git repo?

Thanks in advance.

I have followed this article but did not succeed:

https://dzone.com/articles/push-notification-pwa-reactjs-using-firebase

I want to add notification in my react application using firebase

Comment: Can you tell which errors do you get or explain better the steps failing? 1) Is the service worker running correctly on the client side? 2) Do you create also the server part or use Postman (or similar) to send a correct notification to your client? 3) Is the PushNotification object correctly generated after you grant notifications permission?

Comment: sorry sir i am new to react so looking for a tutorial type article which can help me to integrate push notification in react web application.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [series of articles about PWA](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da). 
You can have a look to get some foundation about this technology.
(I am currently writing the push notification part, so you can re-visit it in few weeks to find it).

GCM ([Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging)) has been deprecated, therefore the post you were following seems obsolete (at least in this part).
Now you should use **FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)** as push service.

Here to learn more about [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). 
And here a [more up-to-date article](https://rharshad.com/web-push-notifications-react-firebase/) about React and Push Notifications that you can follow for your project.